# Dijkstra shortest path algorithm with edge cost

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a directed, positive weighted graph. Each edge have a cost of use.
I have only A money, i want to calculate shortest paths with dijkstra algorithm, but sum of edges costs on route must be less or equal to A.

I want to do this with most smallest Dijstra modification (if I can do it with small modification of Dijkstra). I must do this in `O(n*log(n))` if I can, but i think i can.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: As per usual with homework questions - what do you have so far?

Comment: Am I understanding the problem correctly: Each edge has a length and a cost, and you want to minimize the length with the extra constraint that the cost must be less than or equal to A.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Yes, i want to do shortest path with this extra constraint for each path must be true.

Comment: @Svisstack: does the constraint apply to *edges* or *paths*?

Comment: Must you absolutely use Dijkstra's algorithm, or are other approaches also acceptable?

Comment: @IVlad: If you can do this in O(n*log(n)) complexity without Dijkstra algorithm simple, you are great;-) but i think you can't do in linear logarytmic without Dijkstra.

Comment: @Svisstack: What's this for, out of curiosity?

Comment: @outis: By half. I working as Programmer but in free time i like solving algorithm problems eg. in www.spoj.pl

Comment: Can you link to the spoj problem please?

Comment: @IVlad: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ROADS/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.spoj.pl/problems/ROADS/

The problem was given at [CEOI '98](http://www.hsin.hr/ceoi98/) and its official solution can be found [here](http://www.hsin.hr/ceoi98/solutions/roads.c).

Comment: Perhaps i'm missing something here, but none of those links actually feature an algorithm that solves this problem. The SPOJ submissions contain algorithms, but we can't read the source code to them!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to modify Dijkstra's algorithm to do this as the answer is equivalent to finding the shortest path and then accepting it if it's less than or equal to A.

Of course, you could always short circuit the inner loop if you visit a path with a cost more than A.

EDIT: With the clarification that you want to minimize cost AND distance, you can't do that without clarifying the solution you want. Do you want the cheapest path? Do you want the shortest path? Do you want some function of cost and distance? All of these determine what weighting function you should use for a particular edge.

Comment: The cost and length of an edge are two different things, check out the comments.

Comment: @Bus He did not say anything about a length in his question. As far as I understand the only value associated with each edge is the cost.

Comment: Which of the many meanings Svisstack intended is still unclear to me as well, even after zhe answered Mark's question.

Comment: I think the discussion makes it clear. Mark asked: "Each edge has a length and a cost, you want to minimize the length with the extra constraint that the cost must be less than or equal to A." Svisstack answered yes.

Comment: Then basically, instead of going by edge weights, use djikstra on the edge cost, and you're done oO

Comment: @Rubys that results in the cheapest path, but not necessarily in the shortest path under the price constraint.

Comment: @Bus: it's just that it wouldn't be the first time someone didn't understand a clarifying question, or the alternate meanings and ambiguities in the question.