# Single-source shortest path with distance and weight for each edge

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory, shortest-path

Suppose there's an undirected graph and each edge that connects any two nodes has two weights (i.e. distance and cost). I want to get the shortest path, but also make sure I do not go beyond a certain cost.

I've tried implementing Djikstra's and simply backtracking (for lack of a better term) if I exceed the cost, until I traverse the entire graph. However, I'm looking for a faster solution than this. I've also attempted to use a function that creates a weight given the distance and cost of an edge, but I don't think this will return the optimal solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710516/dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-with-edge-cost).

Answer (score 1):

We can convert your graph from the original graph with `E` edges and `V` vertices `(E,V)` to another graph `(E, V')` with each node `v'xy` in `V'` is the minimum distance to travel from start to node `x` with cost `y`.

So, starting at the start node 0, assuming that we travel to node 1 with distance a and cost b, now, we have our distance matrix:

```
dist[0][0] = 0, and dist[1][b] = a;
```

Thus, this problem become a normal Shortest path problem.

Comment: What are the new edges and edge weights?

Answer (score -1):

Take an weighted average of cost and distance and take it as parameter.

Say average, `p=w*cost+(1-w)*distance`

Now select w as per your cost limit.

Now in any shortest path algorithm will work comparing p.